# Sidebar and body "hiding" under header

Tags: html, css, header, sidebar

I am attempting to add a header image using css into my site. I am very new to css so I'm sure I'm missing some incredibly simple tag so that the sidebar and body are adjusted accordingly.

CSS

```
#sideContainer {float:left;}
.err {
    color: #FF9900;
}

#navMain {
    margin-left:25px;
    color:#999999;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#headContainer {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    height: 150px;
}

#header{
    margin:0px auto;
    height: 150px;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <?php
            require_once('config.php');
        ?>
        <TITLE>Fund Shui Homepage</TITLE>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div id = 'headContainer'>
            <div id = 'header'>
                <?php include 'header.html'; ?>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'sideContainer'>
            <div id='navMain'>
                <?php include 'sidebar.html'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'content'>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the `position:fixed` in your CSS is exactly what you want?

Comment: I got that from another site on creating a header. According to w3schools it `is positioned relative to the browser window` which seems....what I want. Though I'm not entirely sure

Comment: i chagned it to relative and it seems to work. I would not have done that without your comment. If you'd like to put that in an answer i'd be more than happy to give it the green checkmark

Comment: Glad to hear it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `position:fixed`. It may be the same with using `position:relative`.